# SQL Server : how to alter already existing auto_increment for a column

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, auto-increment

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [MyTableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([MyTableId] ASC)
)
```

It already has the `IDENTITY (1,1)`. What I want is to change the auto increment to 2 instead of 1. How do I do that?

I found some answers that says I need to drop the column and create a new one but I'm not sure if there is a simpler solution. Also, I found out that I can do it using SSMS -> Tools -> Options -> Designers -> Table and Database Designers but what I want is the script that I can run as a SQL script.

Thanks!

Comment: does your table already have data? if so, do you want to update it? if not you can modify it in the designer and generate a change script.

Comment: Did you know that most designer actions in SSMS can be saved as a [SQL script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efhhffxd.aspx)?  This is great way to see the SQL generated by SSMS, behind the scenes.  Right click in the table designer and choose *Generate Change Script* from the context menu.  From the new dialog that pops up you can view/save/copy the SQL statement.  At this point you can still back out, so the changes won't be committed if you don't want them to be.

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi This question already have an answer in that post.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza yah :)

Comment: @Tanner Yes my table already has data

Comment: @racumin and do you want to update the values in there?

Comment: No. The values should be the same. @destination-data 's suggestion was the one I wanted. I was able to get the generated script by the SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Revised Answer

You can use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to reseed a table:

```sql
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.MyTable', RESEED, <some-number>);
```

---

### Original Answer

Sorry, you cannot change the increment on an existing [identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx) column.

As you suspected; the process is:

1. Create new table.
2. Optionally, migrate existing data.
3. Drop old table.
4. Rename new table.

A new table is required because existing identities cannot be updated and SQL Server only allows [one identity column per table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx).

**Example**

```
-- Orginal table, with identity column.
CREATE TABLE Original
    (
        X       INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
    )
;

-- New table, with updated identity column.
CREATE TABLE New
    (
        X       INT IDENTITY(2, 1)
    )
;

/* Transfer existing values.
 * Identity insert is require to preserve existing
 * keys.
 */
SET IDENTITY_INSERT New ON;

    INSERT INTO New 
        (
            X
        )
    SELECT
        X
    FROM
        Original
    ;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT New OFF;

-- Drop original table.
DROP TABLE Original;

-- Rename new.
EXECUTE sp_rename 'New', 'Original';
```

**EDIT**

1. As pointed out in the comments below SSMS can automate this process for you.
2. Added example code and more detail.
3. Remove statement that you could add a new identity column, SQL Server only supports one per table.

Comment: I done it using SSMS just now without dropping

Comment: Behind the scenes SSMS creates a new table, moves all your data from the old table into the new, drops the old table and then renames the new table.  You can see this by looking at the change script or running the SQL Profiler.